# ExpandoObject convenience factory?

Tags: c#, expandoobject

Does ExpandoObject have any convenience factory methods? Something like, I don't know,

```
dynamic disney = new ExpandoObject("First", "Donald", "Last", "Duck");
```

Comment: Did you try `dynamic disney = new ExpandoObject {First="Donald", Last="Duck"};`? I am curious if it's going to work (I don't have access to my Windows workstation at the moment to check it).

Answer (score 5):

Nope, there isn't, but you can write it in minutes. :)
Here you go:

C#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic ex = ExpandoFactory.Create("First", "Donald", "Last", "Duck");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.First);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Last);
    }
}

static class ExpandoFactory
{
    internal static ExpandoObject Create(params string[] items)
    {
        //safety checks omitted for brevity
        IDictionary<string, object> result = new ExpandoObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i+=2)
        {
            result[items[i]] = items[i + 1];
        }
        return result as ExpandoObject;
    }
}
```

Of course, you should check the cardinality of the array beforehand.
I hope this helps.

Comment: if you make your loop condition `i+1 < items.Length`, you wouldn't have to check cardinality beforehand.

Comment: Good point, thanks! :) Although, I'd throw an exception if the array has an odd number of elements.